# Cannot use Wagmi hooks in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, ethers.js, wagmi

I have a route component in nextjs that uses wagmi to connect to the smart contracts. The `UseAccount()` works perfectly in the component, but whenever i use `usePrepareContractWrite()` or `useContractWrite`, i get the following error -

```
- error Error: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one
    at Mint (./src/app/mint/page.js:39:87)
null
```

Here is the code -

```
"use client";
import { wagmiConfig } from "../wagmi";
import {WagmiConfig,useAccount,usePrepareContractWrite, useContractWrite} from "wagmi";
import { abi } from "./abi";
import { useState, useEffect} from "react";

export default function Mint() {
  const [expectedAmount, setExpectedAmount] = useState(0);

  const { address, isConnected } = useAccount();

  const { config } = usePrepareContractWrite({
    abi: abi,
    address: "0xe058C0881aC0BF32743b091623708b7FDe75636e",
    functionName: "mint",
    args: [500],
  });

 
  useEffect(() => {
    setExpectedAmount(amount - (amount * 1) / 100);
  }, [amount]);

  const body = () => {
    if (isConnected) {
      return (
       // some frontend ui
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <WagmiConfig config={wagmiConfig}>
     //some frontend ui
    </WagmiConfig>
  );
}
```

A point worth noting is that the the `useAccount()` works perfectly but the error arises only for `usePrepareContractWrite` or `useContractWrite`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by wrapping WagmiConfig around any component that consume wagmi hooks https://github.com/wagmi-dev/wagmi/issues/890.

You have to wrap up the `usePrepareContractWrite` into a separate component that should be included inside `<WagmiConfig>`